# How do you turn a List <dynamic> into a List <Map> >>

Tags: flutter, dart

I started to learn Flutter because I want to build an app which can handle API-Calls.
But now I'm frustrated because I want to make an infinite Load and don't get it to work.
The Problem is, that the method require an Future<List> but I dont know how to convert the response from the API into an List

```
Future<List<Map>> _getServerData(int length) async{
  String api = data.url +length.toString();
  final res=
  await http.get("data.url");
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    List<dynamic> resp = jsonDecode(res.body);
    return resp;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load DATA');
  }
}
```

The whole class is out of an Tutorial from oodavid.
But in his tutorial he dont use an API

```
Future<List<Map>> _getExampleServerData(int length) {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    return List<Map>.generate(length, (int index) {
      return {
        "body": WordPair.random().asPascalCase,
        "avatar": 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/60/${WordPair.random().asPascalCase}.png',
      };
    });
  });
}
```

That was the how he solved it
Down below is the whole class

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:Kontra/pages/articel_list.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:Kontra/api/url.dart' as data;
import 'package:Kontra/api/articelsResponse.dart';

/// Example data as it might be returned by an external service
/// ...this is often a `Map` representing `JSON` or a `FireStore` document
Future<List<Map>> _getServerData(int length) async{
  String api = data.url +length.toString();
  final res=
  await http.get(data.url);
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    List<dynamic> resp = jsonDecode(res.body);
    return resp;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load DATA');
  }
}


/// PostModel has a constructor that can handle the `Map` data
/// ...from the server.
class PostModel {
  String sId;
  String title;
  String text;
  String author;
  String pictures;
  String link;
  int postId;
  String createdAt;
  PostModel({this.title, this.text, this.pictures, this.link, this.postId});
  factory PostModel.fromServerMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PostModel(
      title: json['title'],
      text:  json['text'],
      pictures: json['pictures'],
      link: json['link'],
      postId: json['postId']
    );
  }
}

/// PostsModel controls a `Stream` of posts and handles
/// ...refreshing data and loading more posts
class PostsModel {
  int reload = 0;
  Stream<List<PostModel>> stream;
  bool hasMore;

  bool _isLoading;
  List<Map> _data;
  StreamController<List<Map>> _controller;

  PostsModel() {
    _data = List<Map>();
    _controller = StreamController<List<Map>>.broadcast();
    _isLoading = false;
    stream = _controller.stream.map((List<Map> postsData) {
      return postsData.map((Map postData) {
        return PostModel.fromServerMap(postData);
      }).toList();
    });
    hasMore = true;
    refresh();
  }

  Future<void> refresh() {
    return loadMore(clearCachedData: true);
  }

  Future<void> loadMore({bool clearCachedData = false}) {
    if (clearCachedData) {
      _data = List<Map>();
      hasMore = true;
    }
    if (_isLoading || !hasMore) {
      return Future.value();
    }
    _isLoading = true;
    return _getServerData(reload++).then((postsData) {
      _isLoading = false;
      _data.addAll(postsData);
      hasMore = (_data.length < 30);
      _controller.add(_data);
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: But instead of a list of Map, do you want List of which type of object?

Comment: No I want a list map, but I dont know how to convert it from a List<dynamic> and which params are required
To sum it up, I want that the response has the type that it fit with the return

Comment: @jxstxn__ why do you want list of map? Depending on the json data you should decide what do you want to return as, or use can use model class to map the json data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
return List<Map>.from(resp.whereType<Map>());
```

Or

```
return resp.whereType<Map>().toList();
```

Or

```
return resp.cast<Map>();
```